# Not able to connect WiFi in fresh 17.10 install on Dell 1555

Tags: wireless, 17.10

I have installed Ubuntu 17. 10 on my Dell 1555 laptop. It used to work in earlier version of Ubuntu.

I am able to see WiFi connections. But connecting is an issue.

Please let me know if I need to post any logs.

*update* 
Please find the log for wireless in the below link
https://paste.ubuntu.com/26498339/

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and edit the question to add results.  You may need to paste the contents of the wireless-info.txt file at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL

Comment: I have updated the question with the link to paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your router or access point:

```
Address: <MAC 'virginmedia2835376' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"virginmedia2835376"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001de0638191
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2840ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot the computer and the router and let us hear if there is any improvement.

Comment: I tried this. Now it even stopped showing my router in the WiFi list.

Comment: May we see  a new wireless log after the changes?

Comment: The log - https://paste.ubuntu.com/26509842/

Comment: The connection I am trying now is Adam Wifi. I renamed the wifi SSID when the changes were done. I did that because I coulld not understand if the wifi setting that I changed on the router were saved or not. The "dmesg -w" output can be found here - https://paste.ubuntu.com/26509845/

Comment: Please try changing the name to Adam_wifi; that is, one word, not two.

Comment: Now able to see the connection. But still not connecting. log- https://paste.ubuntu.com/26514717/

Comment: The wifi access point sometimes disappears from the list. log - https://paste.ubuntu.com/26514750/

Comment: Is there any improvement if you power cycle the router? Are you quite certain the router is set to a fixed channel rather than auto channel selection?

Comment: I tried both auto and a fixed channel. Both have same outcome.